# max pool size vs concurrent logins in Azure sql DB

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api, azure-sql-database

I got below exception:

> Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool. This may have occurred because all pooled connections were in use and max pool size was reached.

I have specified the max pool size to be 500. Does it become invalid if the max concurent logins supported by my plan is less? So, if I am using S1 plan and that supports 90 concurrent logins only.

The 91st login will cause the web api to stop working even if the max pool size is 500. I have a service running on almost 500 devices which calls this azure web api (where I have set the max pool size 500). This web api connects to azure DB. Please help me understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Azure SQL Database plan dictates the maximum concurrent logins and sessions. You cannot override this anywhere from your application. The reason for this is when you create the database and give it a plan, Microsoft needs to provide a minimum performance standard for your database. As a result they need to make sure there is room on the underlying SQL server inside of Azure that can handle this. If you change it on the application side, Microsoft won't be able to accurately predict the performance.

You will either need to go to a higher database tier that supports the number of concurrent logins or you will need to make use of the newer feature [Elastic Pools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-elastic-pool) which allows you configure the database to dynamically scale up as needed, then scale back down. Depending on your scenario, this might be cheaper then simply going to a higher database tier.

Comment: Thank u virusstorm. But I have just 1 Azure DB so in my case elastic pools would be beneficial ? I read its beneficial when there are multiple DBs

Comment: The feature was designed for multi-tenant applications to prevent a single tenant from consuming too many DTUs. I think it could work in your situation, but I'm not 100% certain as I don't know enough about your database and application architecture.